# Can java use pdfbox to turn the red stamp into black

Tags: java, pdfbox

I tried to use the following code to convert the stamp color, but it didn't work

```
                    PDFDocumentSignature signature = signatures.get(i);

                    PDPageContentStream contents2 = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, pages,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false, false);

                    PDExtendedGraphicsState r01 = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();

                    r01.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SATURATION);

                    contents2.setGraphicsStateParameters(r01);

                    contents2.setNonStrokingColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

                    contents2.addRect(signature.getX(), signature.getY(), signature.getHeight(), signature.getHeight());

                    contents2.fill();

                    contents2.close();`
```

Comment: What is your "red stamp" / `PDFDocumentSignature`? In particular, is it part of the static page content or is it some annotation?

Comment: it's a seal，not annotation

Comment: There is no structure in pdfs called 'seal'. If by seal you mean a special type of signature, and that signature type is in signature fields and visualized by a widget of that fields, then we are talking about an annotation because form field widgets are special annotations. Or is that seal merely some fancy static graphic in the page? Then we are talking about static page content.

Comment: This is the effect after I use other code conversion, the color of the picture and font have changed, but the seal has not changed

Comment: Ok, your _seal_ is the visualization of a digital signature, i.e. a widget annotation of the corresponding signature field. This explains your observations: Your de-saturating code indeed removes saturation from the static content. But annotations are drawn _atop the static content*, so the annotations are not de-saturated but keep their color, i.e. your seal, the signature widget, does.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer，Is there any way to change the color of this seal?

Comment: Yes. You can do essentially the same thing to the signature widget appearance stream as you did to an additional *page* content stream. Or you add a new annotation covering only the signature annotation with an appearance stream like your one.

Comment: Does the first method have any relevant examples? I have thought about the second method before, but I still think the first method is more concise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out in the comments to the question, the *red stamp* in question is a signature form field widget.

This explains why the OP's code could not de-saturate the stamp: That code de-saturates a portion of the *static page content*. Widgets (and annotations in general), though, are not part of the static page content but are rendered on top of it.

Thus, we have to manipulate the content stream of the widget annotation in question or another annotation over it.

You can manipulate the signature appearance like this:

```java
PDDocument pdf = ...;
PDAcroForm acroForm = pdf.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
PDTerminalField acroField = (PDTerminalField) acroForm.getField("Signature1");
PDAnnotationWidget widget = acroField.getWidgets().get(0);

PDAppearanceStream appearance = widget.getAppearance().getNormalAppearance().getAppearanceStream();
byte[] originalBytes;
try (   InputStream oldContent = appearance.getContents()   ) {
    originalBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(oldContent);
}
try (   PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(pdf, appearance)   ) {
    canvas.appendRawCommands(originalBytes);
    PDExtendedGraphicsState r01 = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
    r01.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SATURATION);
    canvas.setGraphicsStateParameters(r01);
    canvas.setNonStrokingColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    PDRectangle bbox = appearance.getBBox();
    canvas.addRect(bbox.getLowerLeftX(), bbox.getLowerLeftY(), bbox.getWidth(), bbox.getHeight());
    canvas.fill();
}
pdf.save(RESULT);
```

*([ChangeAppearance](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/ChangeAppearance.java#L46) test `testRemoveAppearanceSaturation`)*

| before | after |
| --- | --- |
| [image: screenshot before] | [image: screenshot after] |

Comment: As an aside, I just saw the document by itself contains data for not only the red stamp but also a black (or dark gray) one. Thus, instead of removing saturation we could also have switched between those embedded stamps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, you solved my problem perfectly. The switching method you mentioned later is exactly the method I used before, but there is a problem, because the black stamp was added when I stamped it. It is impossible to turn the stamps in other pdfs into black. Perfectly applicable.